# Linux Terminal: Create directory and subdirectories command

Tags: linux, terminal

I a little bit confused..
if in case i don't have any directory
and then I want to make a new directory with subdirectories
for example I want to make a directory named A and subdirectories B and C
can I directly use :
**mkdir -p A/B A/C**
or must I use
**mkdir -p A A/B A/C**
which is the right one?
Thank you

Comment: `mkdir -p A/B A/C`  -  `-p` says to create the parent directory if it doesn’t exist, in this case: A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, `-p` tells `mkdir` to create the parent directory/ies if it does not exist.  So in your case `A` is created when the subdirectory is created.

Therefore:

```
mkdir -p A/B A/C
```